# Dash showing duplicate icon of application when launched. Why?

Tags: unity-dash

I'm having trouble adding CLion to the dash in Ubuntu. I downloaded CLion zip and extracted it to a directory. I then used "Main Menu" to make it addable to the dash.

[image]

These settings seemed to be good and I could in fact add it to the favorites of dash. But the problem is that when I try to run the application, another icon pops up for it:

[image]

which is not very nice as it takes extra space. How could I avoid this?

Comment: Try right-clicking the new one and add it. If it sticks you can delete the one you created.

Comment: Dash doesn't have the option of adding it. Why wouldn't dash allow me to add this to the favorites? Anther Linux mystery..